# Virtualbox vm goes into aborted state whenever Macbook goes to sleep

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, osx-yosemite, vagrant

I'm running Yosemtie OSX (10.10.2) and Virtualbox 4.3.22.

Whenever my macbook goes to sleep, my vm goes into "aborted" state, and does not recover (i.e. has to be manually restarted/booted).

Looking through the logs in Virtualbox, it looks like it attempts to bring the VM back from "SUSPENDED" into "RESUMED", but gets stuck on "RESUMING".

```
00:01:43.691674 Resuming VM execution, reason "host resume"
00:01:43.692129 Changing the VM state from 'SUSPENDED' to 'RESUMING'.
```

Answer (score 2):

This ended up being an issue with the Vagrant configuration.  The following code in my Vagrant file fixed it for me:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--natdnshostresolver1', 'on']
end
```